# Confuse about env name and env loader

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="rover1">
    <env name="ROS_MASTER_URI" value="http://Master:11311"/> 
    <machine name="Slaver1" address="Slaver1" user="pi"  env-loader="/opt/ros/indigo/env_rover.sh" />
    <machine name="Master"  address="Master"  user="hlr" env-loader="/opt/ros/indigo/env_rover.sh" /> 
    <node pkg="rover_net" name="ControlNode" type="ControlNode" />
    <node machine="Slaver1" pkg="rover_net" name="SensorNode" type="SensorNode" />
    <node machine="Slaver1" pkg="rosserial_python" name="serial_node" type="serial_node.py" args="/dev/ttyACM0" />
  </group>
</launch>
```

AND below is my env-loader file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh
exec "$@"
```

My qustion is since I have set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` but the remote machine is also:

```
Slaver1-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:1131
```

unless I add:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://Master:11311
```

It seems that the `env` name have no work. I am confuse about How the args we set in the launch file pass to the `env_rover.sh`?
Thank for Anything Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221508/confuse-about-env-name-and-env-loader/) by [dsgthlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/25173/dsgthlr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem you mentioned is probably because one can not set environment variable on the remote machine if you not set it inside machine tag. In your case the variable will be only set on local (master) computer.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0